# stack smash error occured in using a staic library

Tags: gcc

i developed a static library, and a test application to call its 
functions.

Now, when i am executing the test application, it was able to get in to
the function and calculate the required values, but when the return is 
called it is giving stack smash error

```
./test_app 
USB Handle opened SUCCESSFULLY
*** stack smashing detected ***: /home/avinay/Documents/iProbe/Experiments/iProbe_linux_lib/test_app terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7ffff7b25807]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x0)[0x7ffff7b257d0]
/home/avinay/Documents/iProbe/Experiments/iProbe_linux_lib/test_app[0x4008ec]
/home/avinay/Documents/iProbe/Experiments/iProbe_linux_lib/test_app[0x4006ed]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ffff7a3c76d]
/home/avinay/Documents/iProbe/Experiments/iProbe_linux_lib/test_app[0x400619]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1186                               /home/avinay/Documents/iProbe/Experiments/iProbe_linux_lib/test_app
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:08 1186                               /home/avinay/Documents/iProbe/Experiments/iProbe_linux_lib/test_app
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:08 1186                               /home/avinay/Documents/iProbe/Experiments/iProbe_linux_lib/test_app
00603000-00624000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff7805000-7ffff781a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 658720                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff781a000-7ffff7a19000 ---p 00015000 08:05 658720                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 
7ffff7a19000-7ffff7a1a000 r--p 00014000 08:05 658720                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7a1a000-7ffff7a1b000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 658720                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7a1b000-7ffff7bd0000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 658699                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff7bd0000-7ffff7dcf000 ---p 001b5000 08:05 658699                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff7dcf000-7ffff7dd3000 r--p 001b4000 08:05 658699                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff7dd3000-7ffff7dd5000 rw-p 001b8000 08:05 658699                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff7dd5000-7ffff7dda000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7dda000-7ffff7dfc000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 658679                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffff7fdd000-7ffff7fe0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff6000-7ffff7ffb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00022000 08:05 658679                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 658679                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Here is the test application

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "leapfrog.h"

void main()
{
unsigned int mid=0x0;

USB_Init();
mid = Read_MID();

printf("\n mid = 0x%x\n",mid);

USB_Deinit();
return;
}
```

The above was the test application and it was referencing this function in the library

```
uint16 Read_MID(void)
{
int8 buf[8]={0};
uint16 mid;
//Read Vendor id
buf[0] = 0xFE;
msp_write(0x41,buf,1);
msp_read(0x41,buf,2);

mid = buf[0];
mid <<= 8;
mid |= buf[1];

return mid;

}
```

till the "mid" calculation i could get the correct values. it is reaching till the end while debugging with insight debugger. just after "}" in the console i see the stack smash error.
what might be the cause of the stack smash.

Thank you for time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding more array space.

```
int8 buf[8]={0};
```

i made it as

```
int8 buf[10]={0};
```